# Explain why this element doesn't render in front

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn how stacking context works and be able to verbalise and explain how this is working with the correct CSS terminology.

I have the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaxgb/2/) example:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="menubox">Menu Box</div>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
    <div class="imagebox">Image box</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header { width: 400px; height: 100px; background: grey; position: relative; }
.header .menubox { width: 80px; height: 90px; background: pink; position:absolute; top: 50px; left: 70px; }

.carousel { width: 400px; height: 90px; background: lightblue; position:relative;}
.carousel .imagebox { width:80px; height:90px; background: yellow; position:absolute; top: 20px; left: 90px; }

/* Here we will change z-index properties and experiment with Stacking Contexts */
.header { z-index:2; }
.header .menubox { z-index:3; }

.carousel { }
.carousel .imagebox { z-index:2; }
```

Which renders as above.
[image: Rendered result]

**The question why does the .menubox not display in front of the .imagebox?**

Here is my attempt at explaining this:

A new stacking context is created on the .header element when the z-index is set. The .imagebox element also has a z-index set to it which also creates a new stacking context. Thus these two contexts can be compared to each other. However even though they both have an equal stacking level (z-index:2) the .imagebox is later in the DOM and hence .imagebox rendered on top.

I feel that my explanation above isn't technically correct and I'm not able to articulate it clearly. Or maybe my understanding is just plain invalid!
Can someone verbalise what is going on with respect to stacking context and stacking levels?

Note: I know that if I set the .header's z-index to 3 this will bring the .menubox totally in front, so I'm not looking for a 'how to fix' it answer.

Comment: You set lower `z-index` for `.header` and `.menubox` is `.header` element so no matter how high `z-index` you set for `.menubox` it's still gonna be inside `.header` which have `z-index` of `2`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, setting `z-index` for the parent `.header` container establishes a new local stacking context, which means that the `.menubox` element will display behind the `.imagebox` If you change the container z-index to 3, it will display in front - see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaxgb/6/)

Also, check out the MDN article on z-index [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). The article explains (about elements with a specified z-index other than `auto`) that

> This integer is the stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context. The box also establishes a local stacking context in which its stack level is 0. This means that the z-indexes of descendants are not compared to the z-indexes of elements outside this element.

Edit: by "container," I meant the `.menubox` parent `<header>` element.

Answer (score -1):

```
.carousel .imagebox { z-index:1; }
```

seems to work